# Projective resolution of complex with bounded degree-wise finitely generated homology over noetherian ring

Tags: homological-algebra

How to prove that over a noetherian ring, a complex with bounded below and degree-wise finitely generated homology admit a resolution composed with free finitely generated modules.

Meaning if $C$ is such that $H(C)$ is bounded below, and $H_i(C)$ is finitely generated for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, then there exists a $K$-projective complexe $P$, such that $P_i$ is free finitely generated for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, and a quasi-isomorphism $\alpha:P \mapsto C$.